# How do I add JSON to the gdata objective-c framework?

Tags: ios, json, gdata

I followed the steps here to add the framework: https://hoishing.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/gdata-static-library-for-specific-api/

When I compile I keep getting this error:

```
error: /devfolder/gdata-objectivec-client-read-only/Source/JSON/SBJsonBase.h: No such file or directory
```

It looks like it's missing all the SBJson headers that's needed for the framework. I can't find where to get SBJsonBase.h though. Is this an older version of JSON? Is there a way to use the latest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking out the API library project via subversion should also check out the JSON parser source files and headers.  The project uses svn:externals to pull in the JSON sources from their own github repository.

Perhaps there was a glitch when the project was checked out to your machine; the JSON files should be checked out into the GData library's Source directory.

Comment: I was using SourceTree to pull the files and it didn't pull the JSON files. I ended up installing fink and using it to pull the library and it worked. Thanks!